# Discord Bot application won't boot up

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I use JavaScript & my app used to work perfectly but then I just edited the `console.log();` thing, then the application stopped booting up. I then rolledback, it worked. I reinstalled the rollbacked version and deployed it to my new application. But then again, it won't boot up; here's log:

```
2018-10-03T06:07:34.458763+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2018-10-03T06:07:35.019124+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-03T06:10:03.251656+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2018-10-03T06:10:03.252202+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-10-03T06:10:04.104471+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-10-03T06:10:04.239401+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-10-03T06:10:06.227488+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2018-10-03T06:10:06.907547+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

It stops at this point, please help.

Comment: Do not prefix the question title with `[tag]` especially if those tags already exits like node.

Comment: What exactly does this `I just edited the console.log(); thing` what line(s) of code did you change into what other line(s). If you alread where able to track down the problem to an exact line, then show this change.

Comment: Just some text changes 
Before: `console.log("Ready");`
After: `console.log("Bot has now booted up.");`